# How do I pull the product cost with Magento API via SOAP?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I am trying to pull a product's cost using the catalogProductInfo command...I successfully pull product data, but it does not include the product's cost. Which API call will return the product cost?

Comment: Which api function are you using to get the product data ?

Comment: I am using this command, but it does not return cost: http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalog/catalogProduct/catalog_product.info.html 
Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: did you print and check the array you're getting from the soap object?

Comment: can you post that data here in your question?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I tried

```
<?php
ini_set("display_errors",1);

$productId = '166';

$proxy = new SoapClient('http://localhost/magento/index.php/api/v2_soap/?wsdl');

$sessionId = $proxy->login('username','password');

$attributes=array();

$attributes['additional_attributes']=array('cost');

$result = $proxy->catalogProductInfo($sessionId,'166',null,(object)$attributes);

echo "<pre>";print_r($result);echo "</pre>";

?>
```

and the response I got is

```
stdClass Object
(
[product_id] => 166
[sku] => HTC Touch Diamond
[set] => 38
[type] => simple
[categories] => Array
    (
        [0] => 8
    )

[websites] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
    )

[created_at] => 2008-07-24T19:22:13-07:00
[updated_at] => 2014-03-12 11:09:55
[type_id] => simple
[name] => HTC Touch Diamond

[weight] => 0.3000
[status] => 1
[url_key] => htc-touch-diamond
[url_path] => htc-touch-diamond.html
[visibility] => 4
[has_options] => 0
[gift_message_available] => 

[price] => 750.0000
[tax_class_id] => 2
[tier_price] => Array
    (
    )

[meta_title] => 

[meta_keyword] => 

[meta_description] => 

[custom_design] => 

[custom_layout_update] => 

[options_container] => container2
[additional_attributes] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [key] => cost
                [value] => 300.0000
            )

    )

    )
```

try it on a stand alone php file with your own parameters

pass the rest of the attributes you require under additional attributes

```
    $attributes['additional_attributes']=array('cost','anything');
```

there are two kinds of attributes, attributes & additional_attributes, you should pass them in an array

```
    $attributes['additional_attributes']=array('cost');
```

or

```
    $attributes['attributes']=array('attribute_code');
```

for more info please refer info method of this below class

```
    Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Api_V2
```

to return these values by default looks like you have to deal with the wsi.xml and api2.xml on your catalog module, but its a little complex way to do it.I'd suggest this approach.

Hope it helps

Comment: I am able to get the product info using a similar call: $product = $client->catalogProductInfo($session, $id);

But it returns information without the cost..here i will include the snippet with the price:

   [price] => 14.5000
    [tax_class_id] => 6
    [tier_price] => Array
        (
        )

    [meta_title] => Product's meta title name

I checked the API user's role, and it has all permissions..so it should be able to access cost..

Any idea why it is not returned in the output? Thanks

Comment: can you confirm that the attribute is enable for all type of products, like simple,bundled etc...

Comment: It is enabled for Simple products, and all of our products are created as simple products...Also a cost value is set for the default, and other stores are set to default (multi-store)... any other ideas? Thanks

Comment: and here is the line of code that makes the API call:
$product = $client->catalogProductInfo($session, $id);

Comment: did you try my answer?

Comment: I'look into it further

Comment: You are right..it is an issue of V2 api...now I tried your script in full and if i input the correct parameters, it returns a cost..Thank you for your help. Any idea, though, why V2 doesn't return cost?

Comment: will let you know once I figured it out

Comment: I've updated my answer for V2 Soap Api,let me if know you have further issues